# VSCode debugs an old file instead of current one

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

Setting up the debugger was already painful but I was able to do it in the end. I wanted to organize my files properly so I made some subfolders and then when I tried to debug any program in my subfolder, it would debug an older file from the main folder that I had debugged sometime before.  
 
Heres my launch.json file
[image: Heres my launch.json file]

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the program that you’re debugging, currently you have that set to `a.exe` to debug another file change this line:

```
“program”: “${workspaceFolder}/a.exe”,
```

to this,

```
“program”: “${workspaceFolder}/path/to/debug/test.exe”,
```

Alternatively, you can add another configuration (i.e. copy-and-paste your current configuration changing the line from above and the name)

Comment: if i want to debug a file from the main folder, i would have to change that line of code again?

Comment: Yes that’s correct, or add another configuration and select the one you want to debug when you go to run it